# iOS app runs fine one simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

So if I run my application on my device I will get this error in the target output. It runs fine on the simulator however.

```
2013-05-30 12:02:43.983 SBrand[2887:907] viewDidAppear:<UIView: 0x1d5b5e20; frame = (0 0; 320 333); autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x1d5b5e80>>
2013-05-30 12:02:43.992 SBrand[2887:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x311812a3 0x38e1b97f 0x310ccb75 0x6e853 0x6d80d 0x6a86b 0x32ff0311 0x3300cf27 0x3300ceaf 0x32f92a33 0x311566cd 0x311549c1 0x31154d17 0x310c7ebd 0x310c7d49 0x34c892eb 0x32fdd301 0x69e83 0x69dd0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

I am not sure where to look because I don't know what `__NSArrayM` is. The app seems to load normally, but then it froze on the first page, after some views have already load, but some view did not.

Comment: It will be helpful if u can share excerpts of code from the First View Controller. Especially lines of code where you allocate, initialize, access the Array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are accessing an array before even allocating it ! or either there are no objects in the array which is accessed in viewDidAppear method. Please cross check !

Comment: Thanks a lot, found the problem.